# AttributeError: module 'jsapp.models' has no attribute 'User_Activity'

Tags: python, django-models

```py
from django.db import models
import datetime

class User(models.Model):

    id = models.CharField(max_length=100,primary_key=True)
    real_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tz = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
```

Comment: The problem is outside of the block of code you have given. Where is the word 'User_Activity' being used in your code?

Comment: Well where did you define a model `User_Activity`?

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this by deleting all files in migrations folder under the app folder then i have done "makemigrations" and "migrate".

Answer (score 0):

At first I have created two models User and User_Activity using a foreignkey then I have done all migrations then I removed User_Activity model so I get a error like that then I deleted all files under migration folder then I have done all migrations then I cleared that error.